# Adding (the latest added Id + 1) when creating a new entry in the database using SQL query

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core

Note: I am aware that this question has been asked before, and I am sorry for such a dumb re-post. **However**, none of the solutions that I've found actually helped me. I might have looked in the wrong place - excuse me for that!

Right, so I am trying to add a new entry in the `Releases` table in my database. The following shows how my code looks like.

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Create(Release release)
{
    var userId = this.User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
    string connectionString = Configuration["ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection"];
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        string sql = $"Insert Into Releases (Id, Name, StartDate, EndDate, OwnerId) Values ('(SELECT MAX(Id) + 1 FROM dbo.Releases)', '{release.Name}','{release.StartDate}','{release.EndDate}','{userId}')";

        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
        {
            command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

            connection.Open();
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            connection.Close();
        }
    }

    return View();
}
```

In my code snippet, I use `SELECT MAX(Id) + 1` in order to insert the new entry with the value of column `Id` + 1 the latest entry. This has worked before for me, but now, for some reason, I am getting the following error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '(SELECT MAX(Id) + 1 FROM dbo.Releases)' to data type int.'

While this solution might not be quite ideal - I am looking for a proper solution to my problem.

Comment: (1) What is the datatype of column `id`? (2) What is the current value of  maximum value of `id` in the table?

Comment: Is `Id` field not an int? Also put a null check `Isnull(Max(id), 0) + 1`.

Comment: The best way is using a stored procedure when the database is multi-user which will lock ID while updating so multiple users do not get same ID and numbers do not get skipped.

Comment: Is there a reason for not using an IDENTITY column - that would also save you from concurrency issues. (The nested select should not be quoted it must be inline)

Comment: not mention that [Little Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/) will f.. you up without parameter

Comment: Can't you just make the ID (as i believe this is your primary key) to 'Identity'. Then you would not have to worry about passing in the id at all.

Comment: @GMB The datatype of the column `Id` is indeed `int`. I just double-checked.

Comment: @AlexK. No reason at all! I just didn't know about that way of taking care of IDs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In answer to your question `'(SELECT MAX(Id) + 1 FROM dbo.Releases)'` should not be enclosed in quotes; `(SELECT MAX(Id) + 1 FROM dbo.Releases)` would return an integer value that is required by your `id` column.

However, you should really be using an [auto-increment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql-identity-property?view=sql-server-ver15) column for your id, as simultaneous requests could try to insert the same id twice.

You should also be using [parameterised](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters?view=netframework-4.8) queries rather than string interpolation, as this is opening up your database to SQL injection.

Comment: Yeah, works now! That was pretty dumb on my part. Glad that I've asked this question as I got info about getting this stuff right using parameterized queries. Thanks a lot for the detailed answer!

Comment: @Questieme please also try to use a propper auto-increment! Both hints are important!